# Какой тип данных использовать в Redis?

Tags: node-redis, redis

Для хранения временной метки последней активности пользователя?
По сути нужно: key(user_id) : timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не так много вариантов: строки, списки, множества, словари. Не сложно прийти к выводу, что для хранения одного значения нужно использовать строку.

Comment: Строка разве имеет ключ? Наверное более подходит Hash

Comment: Redis сам по себе хэш. Хэши, как структуры, нужны в нем, чтобы по ключу доставать сразу множество пар ключ-значение.

Comment: Выходит что с типом данных "строка" я смогу изменять существующие значение по ключам?

Comment: Естественно.